# Can't open Android SDK Manager in Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I've just downloaded it and I've looked at all the other answers.

Android Studio (AS) seems to load fine and I can start one of the template projects.

But I cannot open the SDK Manager (which I want for Ionic). I press the button, I get a messages saying it's loading, a progress bar that fills and then nothing.

I've tried running it as Administrator and it makes not difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i had this problem for hours but figured out how to fix it.

This problem is not due to Android Studio or gradle . Its just because of the updated sdk 24. No need to downgrade studio or anything.  Follow simple procedure:

- close android studio
- Download http://goo.gl/v0UPm6
- goto \sdk
- rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup)
- extract this zip to \sdk
- it will make tools folder in \sdk
- restart studio and errors will be gone

I saw this solution here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/107852486976928213243

Comment: Do you know when the patch is going to be available for sdk 24? Isn't it important to update to the latest sdk verison?

Answer (score 1):

change the sdk\tools\lib\find_java.bat
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/118632/1/find_java/find_java.bat

Answer (score 0):

As [HooKing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402689/3064486) suggested you need to change your `find_java.bat` file located in `sdk/tools/lib` folder.

**This line**

```
                                      v  
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64
                                      ^
```

**Needs a space like this one**

```
                                      v
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
                                      ^
```

Or

**make sure your `android.bat` located in `sdk/tools/` has this line correct**

```
set java_exe="%JAVA_HOME%\java.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in SDK Tools 24.0.0 which makes the SDK Manager not work on some 32-bit Windows systems. When you start Android Studio 1.0.1 you get a balloon saying that Tools 24.0.1 is available; click on it, and then you can install it right from within the IDE (that doesn't use the SDK Manager to do the install). SDK Manager should now work again. If not you can download a fix for the SDK manager directly from 
http://tools.android.com/knownissues 
(see the first issue)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `./android sdk` command works from the tools directory in the sdk. If it fails, try fixing the error. Once this starts working, SDK Manager would start working from Android Studio as well. In my case I was getting the following error
"swt.jar not found in ANDROID_SWT directory. I had ANDROID_SWT path added to my home that was creating problems. Once I removed it, everything started working fine!