# AndroidStudio: Cannot open SDK Manager on Windows7

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I have searched this question on the internet but none of the solutions worked for me. I am unable to open SDK manager and get a ProcessNotCreatedException in the event log. I tried running it from my sdk/tools/lib folder as well, but that did not help. 
I did not update any packages or tools and this problem has seem to come out of nowhere. I tried:

[Android Studio can't access SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313829/android-studio-cant-access-sdk-manager),

[Can't open Android SDK Manager in Android Studio 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387112/cant-open-android-sdk-manager-in-android-studio-1-0).,

[Sdk Manager won't launch in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727109/sdk-manager-wont-launch-in-android-studio),

[Cannot open SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455727/cannot-open-sdk-manager)

But that didn't help as well.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: run as administrator

Comment: I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856650/android-studio-failed-to-open-by-giving-error-files-locked, to run as administrator. Still getting the error! :(